# Should I use the Activity or Message module?

Tags: users, userpoints, status-messages

I want to create a view of user activity on my social site as shown below:

- User A is now following User B
- User C just joined "My_Site_Name"
- User D just gained 30 points for posting "User D_Blog"

I have the user points modules installed for assigning points and other modules such as entity and tokens are also in place, along with rules. What i am not sure is which module should i use: the Activity module or the Message module. I first thought of using the Heartbeat module but its functionalities are all in the Message module as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heartbeat and Activity are both specifically intended for showing user activity (like on Facebook, Twitter, etc.)

Heartbeat is going to be deprecated in favor of Message.  According to the Heartbeat module page:

> This project will be deprecated. The future would be in the module
>   Message. It's much smaller and it cannot be compared to heartbeat when
>   it comes to features. However the possibilities as API would be the
>   same.

Note "the API possibilities are the same."  This means that you will have to write custom code to get Message to do what you want, but as a result you will have more control than the Activity module.

Use the Activity module if you want a solution that works mostly out-of-the-box; use Message if you want to have a highly custom configuration.

Comment: ...it seems to me that Activity is simpler to use...However there are very limited choices provided to create an activity template...how do i create a new hook, such as, user gets points,or which the activity will record messages. Is there a way to do it through UI or will i have to write custom code?

Comment: Fully agree with your recommentation ... though I think you might want to add something (at the very end)) like "Either using its API (in your custom modules) or using site building techniques only with zero custom code). Refer to [my answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/255468/39516) to a related question (from same OPer) for way more details on that.